# Golang oci8 Stored Procedure query produces error

Tags: stored-procedures, go, oracle11g, oci8

I want to query using golang oci8, and this is my setup in oracle xe;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE user_mgt
IS
PROCEDURE login(u_mail_in IN VARCHAR2,
              u_pwd_in IN VARCHAR2,
              retval OUT VARCHAR2)  ;
END user_mgt;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE   BODY user_mgt
   is
        PROCEDURE login(u_mail_in IN VARCHAR2,
        u_pwd_in IN VARCHAR2,
        retval OUT VARCHAR2)
        AS
             l_count NUMBER     ;
        BEGIN
            SELECT Count(*)
            INTO  l_count
            FROM USERTABLE
            WHERE u_mail= u_mail_in;

            IF l_count=1 then
             SELECT u_pwd
             INTO   retval
             FROM usertable
             WHERE u_mail= u_mail_in;
            ELSE
                  retval:='NotFound';
            END IF    ;

        END   login;
    END user_mgt
```

My test below has no error and returns the expected result;

```
DECLARE
em VARCHAR2(50);
pwd VARCHAR2(200);
retval VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
em:='blow';
pwd:='pwd';
   user_mgt.login(em,pwd,retval);
   Dbms_Output.put_line(retval);
END;
```

Now when i try to query in my golang setup i get an error;
package main

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-oci8"
)
func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("oci8", "user/password@XE")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()
    loginStmt,err:=db.Prepare("begin user_mgt.login(:1,:2,:3);end;")
        defer loginStmt.Close()
    mail:="ofoe"
    pwd:="testing"
    var retVal string
    var retStatus string
    er:=loginStmt.QueryRow(mail,pwd,retVal).Scan(&retStatus)
    if er!=nil{
        panic(er)
    }
    fmt.Println("retval")
    fmt.Println(retStatus)
}
```

I will appreciate any help, am really stuck, the error i get is;

```
panic: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too sm
all
ORA-06512: at "BLOW.USER_MGT", line 20
ORA-06512: at line 1
goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        C:/Users/pc/Documents/goPlayground/src/blow.com/oracle_test/main.go:27 +
0x3ab

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
        c:/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:2287 +0x1

goroutine 5 [runnable]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0x12252460)
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:589 +0x43
created by database/sql.Open
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:452 +0x256
exit status 2
```

Comment: Where is the line `ORA-06512: at "BLOW.USER_MGT", line 20` ?

Comment: Line 20(`WHERE u_mail= u_mail_in;`)

Comment: Ah, i figure out. go's database/driver can't pass the variable retStatus directly. So oci8 driver can't recognize how the buffer size is required.

Comment: Is there a way to properly provide the 3rd variable collect the OUT value from the procedure?

Comment: to do it, it must provide a new driver that is not handled as database/sql package.